# Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address[] storage ref

Tags: solidity, arrays, error, state-variable

I am failing to use the push method against a dynamic array declared as a state variable. How can I do this?

I declare a dynamic array of addresses as a state variable like below:

```
contract Sample {
  address[] public path;
}
```

Then, inside a function of this contract, I push two addresses into the dynamic array:

```
path.push(address1, address2);
```

And I get this compile error:

```
CompileError: Sample.sol:91:9: TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address[] storage ref.
        path.push(address1, address2);
        ^-------^
```

Comment: I admit that this error-message is indeed confusing, and that it doesn't imply to the problem in your code. Nevertheless, you should push each address separately, as `push` does not support multiple values at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only push one item at a time. In your case, simply split up your function:

```
path.push(address1);
path.push(address2);
```